# Juniper Junos Pulse for Ubuntu based distros

Tags: ubuntu, vpn

Has anyone been successful using Juniper Junos pulse client on Ubuntu based Linux distros.
I wonder if there are any reliable browser based VPN clients that can be used as an alternative

Thanks

Comment: Did you find any help on this I'm trying to fight with it...

Answer (score 0):

[Alexey Moseyev](https://alexeymoseyev.wordpress.com/2014/10/29/junos-pulse-vpn-client-on-linux-two-phase-auth-64bit-how-to-make-it-all-work) has a solution (now, begin Q2 2015) that works for me. It involves a combination of logging in via the website and then catching the DSID-cookie and passing that into the command-line-client.

I even suggested an enhancement to make sure only the DSID for the specific domain is passed to the command-line-client, adding a where-clause:

```
select * from webappsstore2 where scope = ‘moc.ynapmoc.emos.:https:443′;
```